# Java sockets over internet

Tags: java, sockets, networking, router

I have written a client and server using java sockets. The two machines are on the same network. When I connect using the local IP addresses there are no issues. However if I use the public IP address the connection times out and the client throws "SocketException: connection reset", and the server throws "SocketException: connection reset by peer: socket write error". This happens most of the time, but once in a blue moon the connection actually succeeds. I can successfully ping the servers local address and the router from the client machine.

I have gone into my router, assigned the server machine to a permanent IP address, and forwarded all traffic on the relevant port to that IP address. Unfortunately that was the only thing that I thought could have solved the issue and it did not. I have also turned off windows firewall on the server, still no luck.

The client: (ip taken from whatismyip.com)

```
Socket s = new Socket("xx.xxx.xxx.xx", 27499);
```

to connect.

The server:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(27499, 0, ip);
Socket cs = ss.accept();
```

Any help would be appreciated. I can provide more code if necessary.

Comment: Could be a fire wall issue, could be port forwarding issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can I assume that it isn't a fire wall issue because the server is throwing an exception as well? Implying that there is at least some communication happening?

Comment: I started by disabling the firewall for a test and seeing what happens.  But I'd check the port forwarding settings of the servers connection to the out side world to ensure that the connection is been directed to the server correctly.  I'd also try and 1- connect to the server via a local machine and 2- connect to the sever on the same machine, if you have no issue it's unlikely to be a firewall, but it could still be if the firewall is block external IP ranges

Answer (score 0):

"SocketException: connection reset by peer: socket write error"

This means the server is actually rejecting the connection, could be a firewall issue, the server rejecting the connection, the server actually being down or overloaded.

Comment: This happens when I disable windows firewall too. I can be sure the server is up and not overloaded as this is the sole connection. The line that actually throws the exception is `oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());`

Comment: Print out the stack trace on both client and server to a known location. This can give you a clue on why the server would reject the connection attempt from the client.